# How to add a line break in the CKEditor placeholder?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I was wondering how to add a line break in the CKEditor 5 config.

After reading [the documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/editor-placeholder.html), I do not see any help.

The expected result, following [the documentation example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/editor-placeholder.html#demo), would be to show "content here!" below "Type some".

How can I do this?

`<br>` and `\n` do not work after being added into the CKEditor config.

Thanks